# How do I get unregistered from this site?

Tags: discussion

50 points to answer is ridiculous.  I joined the side with the purpose of adding a comment about David Daniels web site and his research into the Codex Sinaiticus.  The research is very detailed and informative and would have been a good addition to the topic Being viewed.  However, I was not allowed to comment.  Can you get me off of this list please.

Comment: You don't need 50 points to answer, you need 50 points to comment, because commenting is a secondary activity here. Please read the [tour] if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, it took me many weeks to understand how Biblical Hermeneutics works.  Others have answered you question as to why you were not allowed to comment.  It may be frustrating but if you persevere with this site, you will have access to lots of really useful information - and before you know it, you will be able to add comments.

Please don't hit that 'Delete Profile' button yet!